# Search by value in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

Give a pandas series

```
(Pdb) type(dt.ix['some name'])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

(Pdb) df.ix['some name']
col1  5
col2  31
col3  3
col4  12

Name: some name, dtype: int64
```

How can I find the name of the column which has a value, say, 31? In this case it's `col2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```py
myseries[myseries  == 'VALUE'].index.tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.

```
In [13]: df.ix['some name'][df.ix['some name']==31].index[0]
Out[13]: 'col2'
```

THe above picks first value, however if you want all possible values, then do

```
df.ix['some name'][df.ix['some name']==31].index.tolist()
```

Comment: And if I want to get None without having to handle KeyError or IndexError?